# how to sort by count in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angular app and trying to sort items by there count mentioned in the json data but no luck.

here is the [**`Plnkr`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WoM9i1vLUxRykBe60rF9?p=preview).

here is the json code I have mentioned the count.

```
[{
    "name": "Apple",
    "category": "Fruit",
    "description": "This is my dummy descriptionss Nut.",
    "tier" : "t1",
    "all" : "vall",
    "count":"2"
}, {
    "name": "Pear",
    "category": "Fruit",
    "description": "This is my dummy descriptionss Nut.",
    "tier" : "t1",
    "all" : "vall",
    "count":"4"
}, {
    "name": "Almond",
    "category": "Nut",
    "description": "This is my dummy descriptionss Fruit.",
    "tier" : "t3",
    "all" : "vall",
    "count":"3"
}, {
    "name": "Mango",
    "category": "Fruit",
    "description": "This is my dummy descriptionss Nut.",
    "tier" : "t3",
    "all" : "vall",
    "count":"62"
}, {
    "name": "Cashew",
    "category": "Nut",
    "description": "This is my dummy descriptionss Fruit.",
    "tier" : "t2",
    "all" : "vall",
    "count":"99"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change the orderBy dynamically, use something like :

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:filters | orderBy:orderBy">
```

In your code :

```
$scope.orderBy = 'count'; // Use 'count' as default value

$scope.changeOrder = function(prop) {
    $scope.orderBy = prop;
}
```

And change it dynamically on click :

```
<a ng-click="changeOrder('yourProperty')">Reorder By yourProperty</a>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W2kcVRknJEd8pxHW6ZMP?p=preview)